Ceedling Mock Cannot find Files
I am writing code for an MCXA153 dev kit and with my code I am writing ceedling tests.
In my header file for led.h I have the snippet
#ifndef LED_H_
#define LED_H_

#include "MCXA153.h"
#include "fsl_gpio.h"
#include "fsl_port.h"
#include "fsl_reset.h"

#define LED_1_H_PIN     2U
#define LED_1_H_PORT    PORT2
#define LED_1_H_GPIO    GPIO2

#define LED_2_H_PIN     3U
#define LED_2_H_PORT    PORT2
#define LED_2_H_GPIO    GPIO2

#define LED_3_H_PIN     7U
#define LED_3_H_PORT    PORT2
#define LED_3_H_GPIO    GPIO2

#define LED_4_H_PIN     12U
#define LED_4_H_PORT    PORT2
#define LED_4_H_GPIO    GPIO2

#define LED_Debug_H_PIN     11U
#define LED_Debug_H_PORT    PORT3
#define LED_Debug_H_GPIO    GPIO3

#define LED_TASK_TIMES_TO_RUN       0U
#define LED_TASK_INITIAL_DELAY_MS   0U
#define LED_TASK_PERIOD_MS          5U

In led.c all I do is include led.h I have no further includes in my source code.
In my test code I mock all of my headers.
#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS

#include "unity.h"
#include "mock_fsl_gpio.h"
#include "mock_fsl_port.h"
#include "mock_fsl_reset.h"
#include "led.h"

void setUp(void) {
    memset(&leds, 0, sizeof(leds));
}

void tearDown(void) {

}

gpio_pin_config_t led_gpio_config = {
        .pinDirection = kGPIO_DigitalOutput,
        .outputLogic = LED_DEFAULT_STATE
    };

const port_pin_config_t led_port_config = {
   kPORT_PullDisable,
   kPORT_LowPullResistor,
   kPORT_FastSlewRate,
   kPORT_PassiveFilterDisable,
   kPORT_OpenDrainDisable,
   kPORT_LowDriveStrength,
   kPORT_NormalDriveStrength,
   kPORT_MuxAlt0,
   kPORT_InputBufferEnable,
   kPORT_InputNormal,
   kPORT_UnlockRegister};

void test_led_init_should_initialize_all_leds(void) {
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_GateGPIO2);
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_GatePORT2);
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_GateGPIO3);
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_GatePORT3);

    RESET_ReleasePeripheralReset(kGPIO2_RST_SHIFT_RSTn);
    RESET_ReleasePeripheralReset(kPORT2_RST_SHIFT_RSTn);
    RESET_ReleasePeripheralReset(kGPIO3_RST_SHIFT_RSTn);
    RESET_ReleasePeripheralReset(kPORT3_RST_SHIFT_RSTn);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        GPIO_PinInit(leds[i].led_gpio.gpio, leds[i].led_gpio.pin, &led_gpio_config);
        PORT_SetPinConfig(leds[i].led_gpio.port, leds[i].led_gpio.pin, &led_port_config);
    }

    led_init();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(LED_STATE_OFF, leds[i].current_state);
        TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(LED_OFF, leds[i].action);
    }
}

#endif

In my project.yml I have set up my include paths as well as my defines for the project. I am treating externs and inlines as includes. I have gcov setup as well.
---
:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
  :test_file_prefix: test_
  :which_ceedling: gem
  :ceedling_version: 0.31.1
  :default_tasks:
    - test:all
:environment:
:extension:
  :executable: .out
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
  :source:
    - source/**
  :include:
    - include/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/board/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/CMSIS/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/CMSIS_driver/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/CMSIS_driver/Include/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/component/lists/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/component/uart/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/device/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/drivers/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/startup/**
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/utilities/**
  :support:
  :libraries: []
:files:
  :include:
    - frdm-mcxa153-bsp/**  
:defines:
  :common: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - CEEDLING_TESTS
    - CPU_MCXA153VLH
    - MCUXPRESSO_SDK
    - CPU_MCXA153VLH_cm33_nodsp
    - SDK_DEBUGCONSOLE=1
    - CR_INTEGER_PRINTF
    - __MCUXPRESSO
    - __USE_CMSIS
    - DEBUG
    - __REDLIB__
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - CEEDLING_TESTS
    - CPU_MCXA153VLH
    - MCUXPRESSO_SDK
    - CPU_MCXA153VLH_cm33_nodsp
    - SDK_DEBUGCONSOLE=1
    - CR_INTEGER_PRINTF
    - __MCUXPRESSO
    - __USE_CMSIS
    - DEBUG
    - __REDLIB__
:cmock:
  :exclude:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :treat_externs: :include
  :treat_inlines: :include
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:     HEX8
    uint16:    HEX16
    uint32:    UINT32
    int8:      INT8
    bool:      UINT8

# Add -gcov to the plugins list to make sure of the gcov plugin
# You will need to have gcov and gcovr both installed to make it work.
# For more information on these options, see docs in plugins/gcov
:gcov:
  :utilities:
    - gcovr
  :reports:
    - Cobertura
    - Xml
    - HtmlBasic
  :gcovr:
    :xml_pretty: true
    :cobertura_pretty: true
    :html_medium_threshold: 70
    :html_high_threshold: 90
# LIBRARIES
# These libraries are automatically injected into the build process. Those specified as
# common will be used in all types of builds. Otherwise, libraries can be injected in just
# tests or releases. These options are MERGED with the options in supplemental yaml files.
:libraries:
  :placement: :end
  :flag: "-l${1}"
  :path_flag: "-L ${1}"
  :system: []    # for example, you might list 'm' to grab the math library
  :test: []
  :release: []
:plugins:
  :load_paths:
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
    - xml_tests_report
    - gcov
...

Here is a brief overview of my folder structure


When I run my tests I always run as ceedling clean; ceedling clobber; ceedling test:test_led.c to ensure I always have a fresh workspace.
When running test_led.c I always get the error

This is odd to me, it is stating that the file fsl_gpio.h in build/test/mocks/ cannot find a file to include. Looking at fsl_gpio.h in build/test/mocks/ the first line is #include "frdm-mcxa153-bsp/drivers/fsl_common.h". I believe it cannot find this file because it is using an absolute path from within the build/test/mocks/ folder and not the top level folder.
How do I tell this mock of fsl_gpio.c to use a different path?

I'm not a ceedling expert, and have only used it on one project, but on mine, all the things you have under the :include: section of your project.yaml were under the :source: section in mine. I didn't have an :include:section. It all worked for me.

Unfortunately no change.

Well I did some soul searching and found an answer. In the project.yml there are two lines in this block
:cmock:
  :exclude:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :treat_externs: :include
  :treat_inlines: :include

Specifically
  :treat_externs: :include
  :treat_inlines: :include

The header files from NXP have static inline functions defined in the header files. Removing the line :treat_inlines: :include has resolved my issues. I have to fix my tests, but the thing is building!
